# Select all the records having maximum date

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sample Data.

```
Date(YYYYMMDD)  Subject
20170602         Maths
20170602         Eng
20170609         Science
20170609         Hindi
20170616         Maths
20170616         hindi
```

I would like to get output like this-

```
Date           Subject
20170616       Maths
20170616       hindi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select
  t.subject,
  t.date
from
(
  select
    t.subject,
    t.date,
    max(t.date) over() AS max_date
  from
    {your_table} t
) t
where
  t.date = t.max_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) and [cte](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html)

```
WITH ranked AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        rank() OVER (ORDER BY "Date" DESC) AS r
    FROM _table_
)
SELECT 
    "Date", 
    "Subject"
FROM ranked
WHERE r = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the maximum date value and filter your data using it:

```
select *
from your_table
where date = (select max(date) from your_table);
```

It will be pretty efficient if you have an index on the `date` column.